# Is it safe/ok to use UserId as connection id and store it as a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have seen many examples for extendeding the `CreateConnectionId` for the signalR hub class such as these:

http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/

[Storing User On Login then Pushing Data On Demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130132/storing-user-on-login-then-pushing-data-on-demand)

but does changing each user's connection_id to his UserId (keep in mind I am using the the standard asp membership provider out of the box) pose a security threat?  I could see how it would be great to do this so I wouldn't have to keep an internal mapping from users to connection_id's but also thought it could have a security threat if I store it in a cookie on a user's browser.

Comment: Is it possible for a single user to have multiple connections? On the same or different machines?

Answer (score 3):

No it is **not** safe and will eventually break SignalR.

The reason is that if you e.g. use the user's database id and store it in a cookie, the same connection id will be generated when you open a second tab in your browser (as the same cookie will be sent to the server).

This is obviously bad and will break SignalR as soon as you have two tabs or browser windows open, which is not mentioned in the articles you referenced. Additionally, as Icarus described, one could change the cookie and receive messages of other users.

A better way to do it is this:
Keep the default GUID connection id generator and instead add the connection to a group which is identified by your own id (e.g. database id or email address) after starting the connection. This way you can call `Clients[emailAddress].doSomething()` and it broadcasts to all open tabs of this user.

Comment: Good question and good answer, but some code example will be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd adventure an answer and say Yes, this looks like a bad idea because cookies can be easily manipulated and a user may change it to some other random id and start receiving messages/data that aren't intended for him.